# LeafLet pan and zoom behavior

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, zooming, marker

I'd like to perform a pan and zoom effect from one marker to another. For example if the current view is `{lat:m1.lat, lng:m1.lng, zoom:13},` I would do something like this:

```
//Zoom out to initial position

map.setView([center.lat, center.lng], 13, { animate: true });
```

and at the end of transition...

```
//Zoom in to new marker

map.setView([m2.lat,m2.lon],18,{animate:true});
```

Unfortunately, the zoom effect is too fast. So, can I get a smooth zoom?

Answer (score 1):

Use `flyTo`, available in Leaflet 1.0.0-rc1.